# Unity - Player movement problem, you can fly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If you dont collide with something you can fly! its really strange, please help me if you can.
i dont know how to fix it cause i am new in it.

**Here is a script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 4.0f;
    public float gravity = -9.8f;

    private CharacterController _charCont;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _charCont = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        float deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(deltaX, 0, deltaZ);
        movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(movement, speed); //Limits the max speed of the player

        // movement.y = gravity;

        movement *= Time.deltaTime;     //Ensures the speed the player moves does not change based on frame rate
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        _charCont.Move(movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by flying? Is it constantly going up?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) ! When asking questions is best to provide as much information as possible, so other people can help you to the best of their ability. I think adding a better description of what "flying" means, as well as the intended outcome (I assume that is to not "fly"), will help get your problem solved faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that `CharacterController` but it sounds like it takes the global movement vector.

After

```
movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
```

you should erase the `Y` component

```
movement.y = 0;
```